# Adsense shows a blank ads despite the size of the banner is fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, ads, adsense

I have a problem with the banners of Adsense.
I have a page containing 3 banners with the fixed size `336 x 280`. On this page, i see one or more blank ads in a random way. I explain better:

Sometimes I can see only one banner working and the other two are blank, sometimes two banners are working and the other is blank, sometimes none of the banners is working and so on...

The code is the same for all the banners:

```
<div id="banner_rectangle" style="width:336px;height:280px">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 336_280_text_images -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>
```

As you can see in the code of Google there is already a directive for the size of the banner, and there is also the parent div named `banner_rectangle` with the same directive.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I will advise you place all script tags sequentially based on how dependent they are and secondly place all your script tag just before your body tag.

Something like

```
<script ...
<script src="..."></script>
</body>
```